# CSS @keyframe not working

Tags: css, html, css-transitions, css-animations

I have been going through examples and I've go to be missing something here. I can't get this simple css animation to fire, changing the color of some text. When I run the example below, the text stays black.

I have an animation named "changeColor", applied to class "text" for an h1 element. It will fade from one color to another over 5 second intervals.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .text{
                display:block;
                -webkit-animation: changeColor 5s infinite; /* Safari 4+ */
                -moz-animation: changeColor 5s infinite; /* Fx 5+ */
                -o-animation: changeColor 5s infinite; /* Opera 12+ */
                animation: changeColor 5s infinite; /* IE 10+ */

            }
            @keyframes changeColor {
              0% {
                color: 'red';
              }

              100% {
                color: 'blue';
              }
            }
            @-moz-keyframes changeColor {
              0% {
                color: 'red';
              }

              100% {
                color: 'blue';
              }
            }
            @-webkit-keyframes changeColor {
              0% {
                color: 'red';
              }

              100% {
                color: 'blue';
              }
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 class="text">Not Working</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What happened? Did you try any of the solutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are applying CSS, not JS. Just remove the quotation marks in your CSS and it will work like a charm.

[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Hq8v/)

```
.text {
    display: block;
    -webkit-animation: changeColor 5s infinite; /* Safari 4+ */
    -moz-animation: changeColor 5s infinite; /* Fx 5+ */
    -o-animation: changeColor 5s infinite; /* Opera 12+ */
    animation: changeColor 5s infinite; /* IE 10+ */
}

@keyframes changeColor {
    0% {
        color: red;
    }

    100% {
        color: blue;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes changeColor {
    0% {
        color: red;
    }

    100% {
        color: blue;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes changeColor {
    0% {
        color: red;
    }

    100% {
        color: blue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this [**Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/RjpGW/)

You don't need a new `changeColor` rule.
This is sufficient:

```
@-webkit-keyframes NAME-YOUR-ANIMATION {
  0%   { color: red; }
  100% { color: blue; }
}
```

More Animation info [**here**](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/):